Brauer–Siegel's Theorem and application
$\newcommand\underto[1]{\xrightarrow[#1]{}}$Brauer–Siegel's Theorem says that if we consider an infinite sequence of number fields $K_i/\mathbb{Q}$ such that $$\frac{[K_i:\mathbb{Q}]}{\log{|D_i|}}\underto{i\to\infty}0,$$ and if $K_i/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, then
$$\frac{\log(h_iR_i)}{\log(\sqrt{|D_i|})} \underto{i\to\infty}1 $$
where $h_i$ is the class number of $K_i$, $R_i$ the regulator, and $D_i$ the discriminant.
My question is simple, if we work with abelian CM-fields, is it possible that $$\log(R_i)\vphantom{\rule{0em}{-2ex}}\underto{i\to\infty}-\infty?$$
Or more precisely, is $\frac{\log{(R_i)}}{\log(\sqrt{|D_i|})}$ asymptotically bounded ?
Equivalently is $\frac{\log(h_i)}{\log(\sqrt{|D_i|})}$ asymptotically bounded ?

If $K$ is a number field, then its regulator is always larger than $1/5$. In fact, the paper Friedman, E., Analytic formulas for the regulator of a number field, Invent. Math. 98 (1989) 599–622, contains the following result: for every $K$ we have
$R_K\geq R_L$, where $L$ is the unique totally complex sextic field of discriminant $-10051$. In particular, no, $\log R_i$ never tends to $-\infty$ and both $\frac{\log R_i}{\log \sqrt{|D_i|}}$ and $\frac{\log h_i}{\log \sqrt{|D_i|}}$ are bounded from above and from below.

Wow! I had no idea! :) Thanks for this very illuminating answer!

Isn’t there also an explicit lower bound along the lines of $\log{R_K} \geq c \cdot [K:\mathbb{Q}] +d$ for some constants $c,d$?

@Aphelli, you are completely correct! R. Zimmert proved that $R_K\geq 0.04\exp(0.46r+0.1s)$ if $K$ has $r$ real embeddings and $s$ pairs of complex embeddings. The paper is called "Ideale kleiner Norm in Idealklassen und eine Regulatorabschätzung"
